# how to create array with number of columns in sheet dynamically,for remove duplicates in multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

i am new to vba,here i am explaining my situation
1,i want know how to form array in vba with index 1
2,How to give array to remove duplicates**

i want give remove multiple columns in sheet,dynamically i mean if sheet contain 5 rows i want to give
(1,2,3,4,5)
if sheet contain 3--(1,2,3)

here my code:

```
Dim darray() As Integer
 For i = 1 To LastCol1
            ReDim Preserve darray(i)
            darray(i) = i
               Next i

wsDest.Range("A1" & ":" & Cells(LastRow1, LastCol1).Address).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(darray), Header:=xlYes
wsDest.Range("A1" & ":" & Cells(LastRow1, LastCol1).Address).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Header:=xlYes
```

with this code i am get error : invalid procedure call o`enter code here`r argument

**below code is to** conscile data from all files in folder  and sort data and remove duplicates finally want to create pivot table

```
Sub LoopAllFilesInAFolder()

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
FolderPath = "D:\surekha_intern\vba macro learning\assignment\students_data_a3\"
Set wsDest = Workbooks("VBA_A3.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet1")
Filename = Dir(FolderPath)
While Filename <> ""
    
   
    'Debug.Print Filename
    'Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.UsedRange) = 0 And ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count = 0 Then
        Debug.Print Filename; " is empty"
    Else
       
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
     Dim Lastrow_te As Long
    With wb.Sheets(1)
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'down
       Lastrow_te = .Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row
        'Rows.Count, "A"
        MsgBox Lastrow_te
    End With
     Dim LastCol As Integer
    With wb.Sheets(1)
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       ' MsgBox LastCol
    End With

     lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row
   ' MsgBox lDestLastRow
    
    'Range("a1:a10").Copy
    'Range("a1:a10").PasteSpecial
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    If lDestLastRow = 1 Then
    'MsgBox "HI" '.Range("A" & LastRow & LastCol)'"A" & lastRow & ":" & Cells(lastRow, lastCol).Address
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1" & ":" & Cells(LastRow, LastCol).Address).Copy   '"A" & LastRow & LastCol ----"A" & LastRow, LastCol
    wsDest.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    Else
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1" & ":" & Cells(LastRow, LastCol).Address).Copy
    Workbooks("VBA_A3.xlsm").Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & lDestLastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    'MsgBox wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
    'wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LastRow & LastCol).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Range(A & lDestLastRow)
    
    End If
    
    


        
    End If
   ' ActiveSheet.Close
    wb.Close False
   Filename = Dir
Wend
Workbooks("VBA_A3.xlsm").Save
             
 Dim LastRow1 As Long
    With wsDest
        LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'down
        'Rows.Count, "A"
      ' MsgBox LastRow
    End With
     Dim LastCol1 As Integer
    With wsDest
        LastCol1 = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
      ' MsgBox LastCol
    End With
'SORTING
With wsDest.Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A" & LastRow), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Range("A1" & ":" & Cells(LastRow1, LastCol1).Address)
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With
'duplicates remove
 ' Dim darray() As Integer
 'For i = 1 To LastCol1
         '   ReDim Preserve darray(i)
           '  darray(i) = i
              '  Next i
                'MsgBox darray()
                
                
'wsDest.Range("A1" & ":" & Cells(LastRow1, LastCol1).Address).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(darray), Header:=xlYes
'ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Header:=xlYes
'TEXT EFFECTS
 Dim colm As String
 
Select Case LastCol1

Case 1
colm = "a1"
Case 2
colm = "b1"
Case 3
colm = "c1"
Case 4
colm = "d1"
Case 5
colm = "e1"
End Select

 wsDest.Range("a1:" & colm).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
 wsDest.Range("a1:" & colm).Font.Bold = True
 wsDest.Range("a1:" & colm).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
 wsDest.Range("a1:" & colm).Font.Size = 15
'CREATE PIVOT
'Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R1C1:R39C4", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Sheet6!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion12
    Sheets("Sheet6").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Subject")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("marks"), "Sum of marks", xlSum
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Student name")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With

MsgBox "Process done"


End Sub
```

thanks n advance,

Comment: First thing is to qualify `Cells`: `wsDest.Range("A1" & ":" & wsDest.Cells(LastRow1, LastCol1).Address)...`

Comment: Could you share the complete preceding code (starting from `Sub...()`)? You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67263753/edit) your question at any time.

Comment: Do you really want speaking about **5 rows**? Are they columns, in fact? If yes, do you want removing duplicates in **all existing columns**, or in only some of them?

Comment: all existing columns based on sheet contained columns, not on fixed columns count  like hard coded .I want to give dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using an Array for Removing Duplicates

**The Three Conditions**

- The array has to be declared as `Variant` (as you didn't).
- The array has to be **zero**-based (as you didn't).
- The array has to be evaluated using `Evaluate` or `()` (as you did).

**Also**

- Referencing the range can be simplified.
- Always qualify your ranges e.g. `wsDest.Cells...`, `wsDest.Range...`

**Hardly Related**

- If you plan to apply `RemoveDuplicates` to only some of the columns, then using `VBA` with the `Array` function will ensure a zero-based array (`Option Base` related) e.g. `dArray = VBA.Array(1, 3, 4)`.

**A Quick Fix**

```
Sub removeDupes()
    Dim darray() As Variant: ReDim darray(0 To LastCol1 - 1)
    For i = 0 To LastCol1 - 1
        darray(i) = i + 1
    Next i
    wsDest.Range("A1", wsDest.Cells(LastRow1, LastCol1)) _
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(darray), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

**Another Example**

Add a new workbook. Add a module. Copy the code to the module. In `Sheet1` create a table (means headers, not necessarily an `Excel Table`), starting in `A1`, with 5 rows and 4 columns. Use the same data in 2 or more rows (the same for all columns), run the following procedure and see how only one of 'same-data' rows remains. It also includes an optional 'loop handling'.

```
Option Explicit

Sub removeDupes()
    Dim LastRow1 As Long: LastRow1 = 5
    Dim LastCol1 As Long: LastCol1 = 4
    Dim arr As Variant: ReDim arr(0 To LastCol1 - 1)
    Dim i  As Long
    For i = 1 To LastCol1
        arr(i - 1) = i
    Next i
    Sheet1.Range("A1", Sheet1.Cells(LastRow1, LastCol1)) _
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(arr), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please. It assumes that **the first row is relevant to calculate the existing number of columns**:

```
Sub testRemoveDupl()
 Dim wsDest As Worksheet, LastCol1 As Long, lastRow1 As Long, darray()

 Set wsDest = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet!

 LastCol1 = wsDest.cells(1, wsDest.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 lastRow1 = wsDest.Range("A" & wsDest.rows.count).End(xlUp).row

 darray = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:" & LastCol1 & "))")

 wsDest.Range("A1", wsDest.cells(lastRow1, LastCol1)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Evaluate(darray), Header:=xlYes
 'wsDest.Range("A1", wsDest.cells(lastRow1, LastCol1)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(darray), Header:=xlYes 'it works in this way, too
End Sub
```

The problem looks to belong to `RemoveDuplicates` method. It, theoretically should accept an array without any workaround, but it doesn't... It seems to expect an array of variants, not accepting a single variant containing the array, which is not exactly according to the way the method is documented. It is a known problem of this method since some years...