# Delete duplicated rows if the whole row matches using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I'm trying to create a sub that deletes duplicated rows only if the entire row value is duplicated (My sheet have 20 columns). The function `RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes`  will delete the wrong row because I could have duplicate values in all cells, but never an entire row. I tryed using `RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Header:=xlYes` but it gives me an error. So I decided to make the following code. The problem with the code is that I'm going through all cells to verify any duplicate row. Is there any easier way to do this?

Thanks!

```
Public Sub DeleteDupRows()

    Dim plLine As Integer: plLine = 2                   'sheet have header
    Dim plColumn As Integer: plColumn = 1
    
    Dim rowReferece As Integer: rowReferece = 2         'rows and columns used to search
    Dim columnReference As Integer: columnReference = 1
    
    Dim duplicated As Integer: duplicated = False
    
    Set pl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BD - Tarifas")
    
    While pl.Cells(plLine, plColumn) <> ""
        While pl.Cells(rowReferece, columnReference) <> ""
        
        rowReferece = rowReferece + 1
        duplicated = False
        columnReference = 1
        
            While pl.Cells(plLine, columnReference) = pl.Cells(rowReferece, columnReference) And pl.Cells(plLine, columnReference) <> ""   'True remains if we get through all columns
                duplicated = True
                columnReference = columnReference + 1
            Wend
        Wend
        
        If (duplicated = True) Then pl.Cells(rowReferece, columnReference).EntireRow.Delete
        
        plLine = plLine + 1
        rowReferece = plLine
        columnReference = 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: You could use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` and `WorksheetFunction.CountA` row-by-row and count if the number of non-blank cells is equal to the number of cells with the same value as say the first cell in the column.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67265407) is one of my answers which describes 'the three rules' for `RemoveDuplicates`. Basically, you should use `Columns:=(VBA.Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Remove Duplicate Rows (`RemoveDuplicates`)

- When the parameter of the `Columns` argument of the `RemoveDuplicates` method should refer to multiple columns, the following rules apply:

  1. The array has to be declared as `Variant`.
  2. The array has to be zero-based.
  3. The array has to be evaluated e.g. `Evaluate(...)` or just `(...)`.
- The following will remove duplicates if all the values in cells of a row are equal.
- It is assumed that the data (table i.e. one row of headers) starts in cell `A1`.

```vb
Sub removeDupes()
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BD - Tarifas").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = rg.Columns.Count - 1
    Dim cData As Variant: ReDim cData(0 To cUpper)
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To cUpper
        cData(n) = n + 1
    Next n
    rg.RemoveDuplicates (cData), xlYes
End Sub
```

- You could use the range and the `Header` as arguments when you could rewrite as the following...

```vb
Sub removeDupeRows( _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        Optional ByVal Header As XlYesNoGuess = xlYes)
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = rg.Columns.Count - 1
    Dim cData As Variant: ReDim cData(0 To cUpper)
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To cUpper
        cData(n) = n + 1
    Next n
    rg.RemoveDuplicates (cData), Header
End Sub
```

...which you could then utilize e.g. in the following way:

```vb
Sub removeDupeRowsTEST()
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    removeDupeRows rg
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub DeleteRowMatches()
    
    Dim rng As Range, rw As Range, r As Long, dict, k
    
    Set rng = Selection 'for example - put your table range here
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For r = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set rw = rng.Rows(r)
        k = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rw.Value)), "~~")
        If dict.exists(k) Then rw.EntireRow.Delete
        dict(k) = True
    Next r

End Sub
```