# Excel VBA remove Duplicates using for

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to RemoveDuplicates for each column
EX) removeduplicates for A1:A100, columns=1 / B1:B10-, colums=2......so on

and the boldes codes don't work
please help me out

```
Sub DeleteDulpicates()

Dim i As Integer
Dim X As Integer
Dim Endrow As Long
Dim Endcolumn As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ActiveSheet

Endrow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Endcolumn = sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column


For i = 1 To Endcolumn
    
***Range(sht.Cells(i, 1), sht.Cells(i, 15000)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=i, Header:=xlNo***
Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: From documentation, it looks like you need an array of column indexes so `Columns:=Array(i)` may fix the error. (also Endrow doesn't qualify the worksheet (i.e. `sht.` is missing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates

Comment: @Tragamor: For one column a number is fine. For multiple columns, it has to be a `1.` variant `2.` zero-based array, and `3.` it has to be evaluated if you don't want to hard-code it (e.g. `Array(1, 2)`). Check out [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67678989).

Answer (score 1):

You have row and column the wrong way round in `Cells`, and if you are removing duplicates from individual columns the `Columns` argument should be 1.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteDulpicates()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim Endcolumn As Long
Dim Endrow As Long

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    Endrow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Endcolumn = sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    For i = 1 To Endcolumn
        With sht
            .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(Endrow, i)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you you saved my life.....my savior..........my angel.....i love u